# Angular2 resets variable to undefined?

Tags: javascript, angular, amcharts

I am relatively new to angular2 and just finished the tutorial and tour of heroes stuff, from their website and now try to do some stuff with angular and amChart.

Currently i have some trouble with variables that don't keep their assigned value and I don't know, what the problem is - even without amcharts and just using some number type variables for testing, the problem occurs and I think I miss something, im not aware of...

So this is my class:

```
export class SomeComponent {
    chart: AmCharts.AmChart;
    test: number;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.test = 5;
        console.log("number: " + this.test);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        console.log("number2: " + this.test);
        this.chart = AmCharts.makeChart([...]);
        setInterval(this.update, 5000);
        console.log("number3: " + this.test); 
    }

    update(): void {
        console.log("number in update:" + this.test);
        [...]
    }
}
```

and this is my output:

```
number: 5
number2: 5
number3: 5
number in update: 5
number in update: undefined
```

So obviously, test is initialized with the value 5 in `ngOnInit` and keeps it value until `ngAfterViewInit`. However when update is called from `SetInterval`, then test is "undefined".

Thanks in advance for any help or helpful links.
:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing method or function references this way "breaks" `this.`

```
setInterval(this.update, 5000);
```

Use `.bind()`

```
setInterval(this.update.bind(this), 5000);
```

or arrow functions

```
setInterval(() => this.update(), 5000);
```

to fix the problem

Comment: learned something again - thank you ! :) can not accept answer for the next 4 minutes, will do so afterwards

Comment: That's developers life :)